# notation question

Tags: notation

I have a model that I have built but have used psuedo notation to build it in code. Now that the write up is happening, I am a little stuck and may need some help. I was wondering what the best way to present this is. Basically my model involves 10,000 types of people, and there are 2 skills that they all own, lets call them social skills, and mathematical skills from 1 to 100. So say individual i has 34 for maths and 42 for social skills, what would be the best way to represent that, given that i need to use those values in other variables?

Comment: I think you need to add more information.  What's wrong with writing $s_i, m_i$ as the social, math skills of the $i^{th}$ individual?  So if your man is $\#1$ then $s_1=34, m_1=42$.

Comment: to be honest I think you are right